# correct Http Request header field to pass some flags

Tags: api, rest, http, https, http-headers

Can someone suggest correct HTTP request header field to use to pass some flag using Rest API call. Can I use 'expect' request element for this use case?

Use Case:

Read client request header-->read the flag(say value is 1 or 0) --> do task A for value=1 or task B for value=0

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not an appropriate use of the `Expect` header. Depending on your exact use case, you can use (a) a custom header, (b) a query parameter, or (c) embed the flag in the entity being sent to the server. Without more information, it's impossible to say which is most appropriate for your situation.